# CSS to turn a certain color depending on angularjs condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
 <div>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" 
         style="margin-top: -50px; cursor:pointer; color: #1F45FC" 
         ng-click="createComment(set_id)">
      </i> Route 
      <center>
           <span class="route_no">{{set_id}}</span> 
      </center>
 </div>

 <div>
      <center>Status: {{set.total_one}}/{{set.total_two}}</center>
 </div>
```

This is inside an `ng-repeat="set in settings"`

I want to change the color of my `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">` depending on a condition inside my javascript controller.

I'm having trouble binding the specific icon to an index so that angularjs knows which icons to change color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fixing the classes, you can use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) to assign a class when the condition is true.

If your condition is a boolean `flag` property of your `set`, and you want to add a class called `red` when it is true, you would do it like so:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"
   ng-click="createComment(set_id)"
   ng-style="{ red: set.flag }">
```

Alternatively you can use an expression that evaluates to the class name, the ternary operator comes in handy here. For example if you wanted the first 3 `red`, and the rest `blue`:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"
   ng-click="createComment(set_id)"
   ng-style="$index < 3 ? 'red' : 'blue'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in your controller that will, based on a condition return the needed color. Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phenc3Lj/1/)

This is the function, where you can apply the necessary logic:

```
this.getColor = function (cust) 
{ 
    if (cust.total_one > 400) return 'red';
    if (cust.total_one > 300) return '#FF4700';
    if (cust.total_one > 200) return '#FF9900';
    if (cust.total_one > 100) return 'yellow';
};
```